# How to import igraph and its settings (coloring of nodes etc) in cytoscape?

Tags: r, igraph, cytoscape

**What I'm trying to do**

I am using igraph R package to create and visualize a network of interest.

The layout in R is pretty bad. I would like to import my network in Cytoscape in order to arrange the layout myself.

**What isn't working**

I save my igraph object and use RCy3 R package (function createNetworkFromIgraph) to export it in cytoscape. However, the network formatting (node colora etc) is lost! Is there a way to keep the formatting and transfer it to Cytoscape?

### My code

```
library(igraph)

network_graph <- graph_from_data_frame(d = network_df, directed = F)  
vertices = unique(as.character(network_df[,2]))
netm <- get.adjacency(network_graph, sparse = F)
```

network_df is a data.frame with source, target and value. Here is the head:

```
  source      target  means
  colchicine  TUBB1 0.08330359
  colchicine    TTL 0.08330359
  colchicine  TTLL2 0.08330359
  colchicine TUBA4A 0.08330359
  colchicine TUBB2B 0.08330359
  colchicine   BRD4 0.08330359
```

**Choice of layout (fr or kk are both good for sparse graphs)**

```
l <- layout_with_fr(network_graph)
```

**Normalization of coordinates, so we know how large the figure is in base graphics coordinates**

```
l <- norm_coords(l, ymin=-1, ymax=1, xmin=-1, xmax=1)
```

**Give a scalar of colors to the nodes. Provide breaks for the values of the nodes, so that they fall in a different color shade**

```
pal <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "slateblue"))(6)
values <- network_df$means
bks <- pheatmap:::generate_breaks(values, length(pal), center = F)
cols <- pheatmap:::scale_colours(values, col=pal, breaks=bks, na_col = "grey")
network_df$cols <- cols
shapes = c(rep('square',10), rep('circle', dim(network_df)[1]-10)) 

save.image('igraph_drug_targets.RData')
```

**This is the part that i want to draw in Cytoscape**

```
plot(network_graph, rescale = F, layout=l*1.0, vertex.label = NA, 
vertex.shape=shapes, vertex.frame.color = "gray20", edge.arrow.size = 
.5, vertex.color = network_df$cols, vertex.size = 5,  edge.color = 
rgb(0,0,0,0.4), edge.width = 0.3, xlim = c(-1.3, 1.3), ylim = c(-1.3, 
1.3))
```

**Add custom text labels**

```
for(j in 1:nrow(netm)) 
text(l[j,1], l[j,2], labels=rownames(netm)[j], pos = 3,  cex = 0.7, font = 2)
```

**Generate the y coordinates for rectangles within the color key**

```
rect_series = seq(0.3, 1, length.out = max(network_df$means) + 1)
```

**Loop to draw rectangles within the color key**

```
pal2 <- c(pal1[1], rev(pal[1:length(pal)-1]))

for(q in 1:max(network_df$means+1)){ 
    rect(1.1, rect_series[q], 1.2, 
    rect_series[q+1], col = pal2[q], border = NA)
    rect(1.1, 0.3, 1.2, 1)
    text(1.2, 0.3, min(network_df$means, 2), pos = 4)
    text(1.2, 1, round(max(network_df$means, 2),2), pos = 4)
    text(1.2, 1.1, labels = "Log10 normalized counts", pos = 4)

}
```

Comment: As idea, if you don't like iGraph layouts, you can try `ggraph`, a very nice blending between `iGraph` and `ggplot2` without going out `R`. Clearly it's an hint, not the answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Since no code is posted, I'll suggest some alternatives.

What I would do is create a dataframe that contains the network (a 2 columns, N rows dataframe) which you can easily export from R and import in Cytoscape as a **.sif** file.

Then I would create another dataframe containing nodes attributes:

```
  Node_Name | Attribute_1 | ... | Attribute_N
   node1    |   protein   | ... |    ...
   node2    |     RNA     | ... |    ...
   nodeN    |    gene     | ... |    ...
```

etc... so that you can import is as a Table, in Cytoscape. By doing so you're now able to exploit the potential of the Cytoscape Style editor. Consider that the attributes given to the nodes are useful to apply specific shapes, colors and sizes to the different kinds of nodes.
The same works for edges (maybe you need different kinds of edges too): create a dataframe containing edges attributes and import it in Cytoscape.

If you want to go through R and want to create nice graphs with it, I strongly suggest you to have a look at this link: http://kateto.net/network-visualization

edit:

it seems that RCy3 on my R version is not working hence I can't really help you by providing code.

But, since in Cytoscape you can create, import, export and apply to networks your own custom styles, what I believe you should do is the following.
Using the function you suggested, i.e. **createNetworkFromIgraph()**,  you build a Cytoscape graph. Then, you should create a new style using the function **createVisualStyle()** and, finally, you should apply this style to the network, as mentioned here: https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/RCy3/man/RCy3.pdf

hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and for the nice tutorial that you suggested (really good!) I am sorry I did not include code in my original post. I now edited it, so I hope it is clearer. I would like to visualise in Cytoscape the plot that I am creating in my script. What do I need to export from my script so that I can then use RCy3 function createNetworkFromIgraph() and get my desired plot in Cytoscape?

Comment: Still it is not possible to test the code since there is not a sample of your datasets.

I guess that network_ds is a matrix with at least 3 cols: 
source | target | weight of interaction

but...df_all? what does it contains?

Comment: I am sorry, it is network_df there as well, not df_all...I had more data.frames in my original script. I simplified my original script for posting it here. I updated my code in my original post respectively and added the head of network_df (It is a drug-target network from STITCH)